# Can an unconfirmed transaction that only Blockchain.info shows be manually re-broadcast?

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, peers, raw-transaction, broadcast

Blockchain.info shows a transaction that was created by Blockchain.info/wallet but for whatever reason the transaction didn't confirm right away and appears to not be getting re-broadcast (perhaps because the transaction is more than a day old now).

Is there a way to recreate the transaction (reconstruct as an identical copy, resulting in the same transaction hash) using just the data shown from the blockchain.info website (the Input scripts and Output scripts from the transaction's view on the site) to construct a raw transaction that I can manually re-broadcast using http://Blockchain.info/pushtx or http://brainwallet.org/#tx ?

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but answer might be helpful for someone.

To get a raw transaction append:

```
?format=hex
```

to the transaction URL.

For example:

```
https://blockchain.info/tx/1b087a7aebdd06740bd4ffefba076562b582a97f02cedf2cd32f53f7eb0b3c8c?format=hex
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

All the data you need to assemble it is there on blockchain.info.
Just follow the TX format and you can do it.
I did it myself, so I can assure you that it would work.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#tx

Comment: I had a transaction that had taken 90 minutes without being put in a block from Coinbase. I tried getting the raw transaction from Coinbase and submitting it on http://blockchain.info/pushtx but I couldn't get it to parse. If I could have would that have gotten it in a block faster? Here is the transaction: https://blockchain.info/tx/1c12a9f7db650956e3c01d7cd86fe8b4dd281e4d5dfc98f00af90803b158024f

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you unfortunately can't find the raw transaction anywhere on blockchain.info. Also, do note that http://brainwallet.org/#tx actually just uses pushtx. Anyway, even if you did have the raw transaction, you couldn't put it into http://blockchain.info/pushtx as long as it still appears on the bc.i website -- it would just reject it as a duplicate. If you did have the raw transaction, you could rebroadcast it through a client -- bitcoin-qt or bitcoind's sendrawtransaction RPC call, for example.

EDIT: You can get the raw transaction from blockchain. Go to the transaction and put ?format=hex at the end of the URL

Comment: Are you sure brainwallet #tx uses blockchain.info's pushtx?

Comment: It opens a dialog box, asking "Press OK to send transaction to:" and it's prefilled with http://blockchain.info/pushtx. I don't know if you can put other things in there and have it work, but I know that that's what it used by default.